# Copiar estructura de tablas MySQL sin los datos

Tags: mysql

En MySQL, puedo copiar la ¿estructura?  de una tabla mediante este comando:

```
CREATE TABLE foo SELECT * FROM bar LIMIT 0;
```

Haciendo esto voy a tener una tabla `foo` con las mismas columnas de la tabla `bar`, pero en la tabla `foo` no habrá datos.

Pero, ¿qué ocurre con los índices, las restricciones (constraints), las llaves foráneas? ¿Se copian también?

Si no se copian, ¿cómo podría hacer una copia exacta de mi tabla `bar` sin datos, pero que tenga la misma configuración que `foo` en cuanto a índices, restricciones, etc?

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de ello, lo que si es con Workbench puedes crear los scripts de la base y te da la opción de solo el esquema, esquema y datos, o solo datos.

Comment: Sí @M.Gress Yo lo he hecho así desde PHPMyAdmin, pero quiero saber si hay forma de hacerlo mediante una consulta del tipo `CREATE TABLE` sin tener que entrar a PHPMyAdmin. Se trata de una bd remota a la cual me conecto mediante el programa Coda. Me resulta muy pesado tener que entrar cada vez a PHPMyAdmin para ejecutar ese tipo de consultas. Desde Coda puedo crear tablas y hacer consultas sin tener que ir a PHPMyAdmin, previo login en cPanel.

Comment: Oh ya, entiendo, no pues entonces esperemos a ver si alguien ya lo ha logrado mediante un comando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una posibilidad sería:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo LIKE bar;
```

Comment: Sí Señor, `LIKE` era el comando. Muchas gracias.